# Tensorflow R-CNN network Small Object Detection - side by side objects, one classified correctly, the other entirely missed

Tags: tensorflow

Using Faster R-CNN with Resnet-101. I'm detecting small object in fairly large images. For each image, a number of my objects will be detected, with high accuracy (98-99%). However, randomly, other nearly identical objects in the image are completely missed.

To further illustrate the issue - if I flip or rotate the image, then a different bunch of objects will be classified (with the same high accuracy), and objects classified in the previous configuration may be missed.

It's like only certain regions of the image are checked for an object - if the object is within that region, it will be detected easily, if not, if will be entirely missed.

Changing first_stage_features_stride from 16 to 8 helped A LOT (quadrupled the number of objects detected overall). Otherwise, I'm using essentially out-of-the-box config. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you achieve your goal. If so can you please share your github project ?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to modify the scale and aspect ratio of the anchor generator, you can also test the anchor generator to make sure it covers the whole image. 
Please see the following link: [tensorflow object detection](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/anchor_generators/grid_anchor_generator.py)

Comment: Thanks. My current scale is [0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0]. What would you suggest as some values to start trying? Should I make them all smaller - e.g. [0.05, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5]; or, just the first two - e.g. [0.1, 0.25, 1.0, 2.0] ?